# Pydroid3 opencv -215 assertion failed (permission issue)

Tags: python, android, opencv, mobile, pydroid

I have 2 xiaomi smartphones: Xiaomi Redmi 3 (lineageOS, Android 11) and Xiaomi Mi9 lite (MIUI, Android 10).
(The goal is to use Redmi 3 on my pet project).
I tried to run the same piece of code on both devices, but its work only with Mi9 lite.

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, img = cam.read()
cv2.imwrite('qqq.jpg', img)
```

On redmi 3 I've got the error:
[image]

looks like some premission issue, cause opencv cant get the image from camera.
And idk how to solve that, i already got Pydroid permission plugin but that doesnt work.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. remove the screenshot, post the text it contains. -- you don't have image data, so you can't write what you don't have. -- why did you not error-check VideoCapture? `assert cap.isOpened()` and `if not s: break`

Comment: I know that, the question is how can i get image from the smartphone camera in that case.
I assumed that this is due to the limitation of the application, there are no access rights to the camera. But that was a camera problem, pydroid opencv doesnt support this version of camera API.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pydroid can work properly only with Camera 2 API.
[image]

But redmi 3 camera has not that technology:

[image]